# Sending http post request in Ruby by Net::HTTP

Tags: ruby, http, http-headers

I'm sending a request with custom headers to a web service.

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

uri = URI("https://api.site.com/api.dll")
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true
headers = 
{
    'HEADER1' => "VALUE1",
    'HEADER2' => "HEADER2"
}

response = https.post(uri.path, headers) 
puts response
```

It's not working, I'm receiving an error of:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1932:in `send_request_with_body': undefined method `bytesize' for #<Hash:0x00000001b93a10> (NoMethodError)
```

How do I solve this?

P.S. `Ruby 1.9.3`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The second argument of `Net::HTTP#post` needs to be a `String` containing the data to post (often form data), the headers would be in the optional third argument.

Answer (score 15):

Try this:

For detailed documentation, take a look at:
http://www.rubyinside.com/nethttp-cheat-sheet-2940.html

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'

uri = URI('https://api.site.com/api.dll')
https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
https.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.path)

request['HEADER1'] = 'VALUE1'
request['HEADER2'] = 'VALUE2'

response = https.request(request)
puts response
```

Comment: How can I post a json body with this?>

Comment: `data = { "aaa" => "111" }.to_json; request.body = "[ #{data} ]"`

Answer (score 2):

As qqx mentioned, the second argument of `Net::HTTP#post` needs to be a `String`

Luckily there's a neat function that converts a hash into the required string:

```
response = https.post(uri.path, URI.encode_www_form(headers))
```

Comment: Form data and headers are completely different. Yes, you can convert the Hash of headers to form data, but this likely won't give the expected results. If `headers` actually contains data that should be sent as form contents, I'd say that's a very badly named variable and should be renamed.